# How to get the key of all the Azure Services in same way through powershell

Tags: powershell, azure

I am trying to develop a  PowerShell script for getting the key using `Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction` command of different Azure services, like below

```
$keyValue=Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction  -Action listKeys  -ResourceId $ResourceId  -force
```

The problem is, I am getting the key to different services in a different way. Like for storage account, I have to write `$keyValue.keys[0].value`  for getting the 1st key value. But for cognitive service, I have to write `$keyValue.key1`. Is there any way to generalized it so that same thing works for all the services in Azure which has the s key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could not access it via the same command. Different azure services have different resource structures, so the result format of the command will be different.

I recommend you to add logic to judge different services in your commands and run different command for them.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Is there any way to manipulate the variable ($keyValue in this case) in which i am storing the key and get the job done for all other services.

Comment: @NiteshSingh It seems not, the variable that returned by the command was not controlled of us, like some result will be `key:value`, some will be `key:xxx`, we just control the format for the result at most, but not the structure.